# Derivative and Taylor Series

Tags: calculus

In higher dimensions, is the derivative (jacobians,gradients etc.) defined using taylor series or taylor series formula proved through derivatives ?

Comment: I would say that on most of textbooks  you introduce at first directional derivatives, then partial derivatives, then you define differentiability and at last you define Taylor expansions /series using the previous structures.

Comment: @Avitus Yes, but structures like Jacobians etc. are made keep linear approximation to functions in mind.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, we'll have to ask Taylor himself.
But I can tell you that Taylor's Series is a **Theory**, and originally it is based on linear approximation which is one of the derivatives applications, and he developed it to give a general approximation with the same derivatives concept (based on the equation of a straight line $y=mx+c$).

In fact when I first learned it, I was as curious as you, so I kept searching and trying until I could find an Algebraic solution, if you're interested I can add it to the answer.

However, I'm almost sure it's based on the graphical analysis.

I advise you to read the wikipedia artice about it, it's really useful and understandable.

I hope I answered your question :)